# Use accelerometer to rotate screen

Tags: drivers, screen, hp, display-rotation, rotate

```
lsmod | grep acc
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
```

How do I get output out of this thing?

and there's `xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal` or `inverted` or `left` or `right`. I want to use the sensor output to trigger those command & do screen rotation.

**edit:**

After upgrading kernel now I get this when I run `lsmod | grep acc`

```
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  1
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  15 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio           69632  10 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,acpi_als,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,industrialio_triggered_buffer,kfifo_buf
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8 hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
```

**edit2:**

iio-sensor-proxy isn't running. Trying `sudo iio-sensor-proxy` gives

```
** (process:2721): WARNING **: Failed to read float from /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/{33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}/001F:8086:22D8.0001/HID-SENSOR-200073.8.auto/iio:device6/in_scale

** (process:2721): WARNING **: Problem reading scan element information: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/{33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}/001F:8086:22D8.0001/HID-SENSOR-200073.8.auto/iio:device6
```

and the terminal remains blank till I `^C`.

Trying `sudo systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy` outputs nothing till it timeouts

```
Job for iio-sensor-proxy.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status iio-sensor-proxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status iio-sensor-proxy.service`

```
● iio-sensor-proxy.service - IIO Sensor Proxy service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iio-sensor-proxy.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2017-05-24 16:12:03 EET; 5min ago
  Process: 3335 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iio-sensor-proxy (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 3335 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

May 24 16:10:33 gas systemd[1]: Starting IIO Sensor Proxy service...
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: Failed to start IIO Sensor Proxy service.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

`journalctl -xe` (probably not very useful)

```
May 24 16:11:26 gas kernel: intel-vbtn INT33D6:01: unknown event index 0xcd
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: Failed to start IIO Sensor Proxy service.
-- Subject: Unit iio-sensor-proxy.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit iio-sensor-proxy.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 24 16:12:03 gas systemd[1]: iio-sensor-proxy.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 24 16:12:03 gas sudo[3855]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:12:17 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:13:40 gas anacron[775]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 24 16:13:40 gas anacron[775]: Normal exit (1 job run)
May 24 16:13:50 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:14 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:14:43 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:15:01 gas CRON[4519]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 24 16:15:01 gas CRON[4520]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 24 16:15:01 gas CRON[4519]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 24 16:15:02 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:15:15 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:15:26 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:15:49 gas /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[790]: snapmgr.go:450: No snaps to auto-refresh found
May 24 16:15:49 gas snapd[790]: 2017/05/24 16:15:49.321528 snapmgr.go:450: No snaps to auto-refresh found
May 24 16:15:51 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:13 gas gnome-session[2010]: (nm-applet:2383): nm-applet-WARNING **: ModemManager is not avai
May 24 16:16:58 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:17:01 gas CRON[4669]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 24 16:17:01 gas CRON[4670]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 24 16:17:01 gas CRON[4669]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 24 16:17:46 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable 
May 24 16:18:00 gas org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1779]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2514): WARNING **: Unable
```

...and yes my computer's name is gas X'D

I hope we can fix this sensor thing. I'm desperate to get it to work. It seems that we're getting there :)

Comment: This might help you : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116275

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution but a pointer in the right direction. I've also hunted for a method to do this. I've come across iio-sensor-proxy https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy and I'm in the process of writing a small daemon that will sort this out.

This is what I get when I run monitor-sensor and turn the screen 90 degrees to the right.

> ```
> > monitor-sensor 
>     Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
> +++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
> === Has accelerometer (orientation: undefined)
> === Has ambient light sensor (value: 0.000000, unit: lux)
>     Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
>     Light changed: 6.098000 (lux)
>     Light changed: 168.823008 (lux)
>     Light changed: 167.266008 (lux)
>     Light changed: 161.816008 (lux)
>     Light changed: 183.098009 (lux)
>     Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
>     Light changed: 204.379010 (lux)
>     Light changed: 214.241010 (lux)
>     Light changed: 214.371010 (lux)
>     Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
>     Light changed: 179.724009 (lux)
>     Light changed: 170.121008 (lux)
>     Light changed: 170.900008 (lux)
> ```

Comment: when I run `monitor-sensor` I get no output :( ..thx X)

Comment: What does `gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.SensorProxy --object-path /net/hadess/SensorProxy` say?

Comment: `Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name net.hadess.SensorProxy was not provided by any .service files
`

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed iio-sensor-proxy or the configuration files for it. I'm not sure. I'm on Opensuse tumbleweed so yours maybe different in how it is installed and started.

Comment: but I do have it installed. what else may cause this error?

Comment: You might have run into this [link](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy/issues/71#issuecomment-245760459)

Comment: mmm so I should try update to kernel 4.9?

Comment: okay upgraded to 4.10.0-21-generic as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/236458/174392) but I get the same results with everything. also see edits in the question

Comment: Do you have iio-sensor-proxy running? Check with ps or pidof
`ps waux | grep iio` or 
`pidof iio-sensor-proxy`

Comment: see edits. we need to find out what's preventing the service from starting up